# Android Bluetooth Advertisement - Internal Error

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android, bluetooth-gatt

I have a Android Device advertising as Bluetooth LE GATT Server. Sometimes (roughly in 20% of the cases) when I start advertising it fails with the `OnStartFailure` Callback giving me the error Code `internal error`. Does anyone has experienced this issue and has some tipps on how to overcome it? Is there any way to get more information about the nature of the error, internal error is pretty generic?

Some more information about what I am doing:

- I run two different advertisements at the same time. The first advertisement acts as iBeacon (implemented with altbeacon library).
- The second advertisement is a connectable one, which also advertises a service UUID and 2 bytes of advertisement data.
- The error sometimes occurs when I start the beacon advertisement and sometimes when I start the other advertisement
- I am using Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by programmatically deactivating and then reactivating Bluetooth on the device. The problem seems to be solved after bluetooth is restarted in that way.